# Connection string for mirrored database on Azure in Azure Websites

Tags: azure, connection-string, database-mirroring

I have database mirroring setup on Azure as outlined in this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870961.aspx). My question is how do I connect to the database in ASP.net? I know I can use `Data Source="DB1";Failover Partner="DB2"` in my connection string but the problem is that my three VM's are using the same cloud service meaning their public IP addresses are all the same as well as their URL's. I originally thought I might be able to access them using their internal IP addresses, but Azure Websites does not seem to allow me to select which Cloud Service it runs under.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

With no easy answer for time being (Jan. 2014)! The issue is that, the easiest way is really use Internal IP Addresses. This will only be possible if all the resources are part of the same Virtual Network. But as of today, Azure Web Site cannot be part of Azure VNet. So, the easy answer is - you can't really do that.

The tough one is - you have to manage a middle-ware load-balancer of your own, or use a different configuration for SQL Server Fail Over or High-availability. Either of the solutions are too broad and primarily opinion based to further discuss them.

UPDATE based on the comments

Actually there is a way to have 2 Public IP Addresses for the machines. You can deploy the two VMs to separate cloud services. Still the same Virtual Network. The limit is 1 public address per Cloud Service. And your Azure VM is actually deployed to a cloud service. So put each VM in its own Cloud Service and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! BTW its 2014 :) So I guess the only way is to move over to a different configuration. I know its personal opinion, but are any of the other options going to put me in a similar position?

Comment: Although not ideal, is there no way for me to have two public ip addresses for each of the VM's? Or should I completely forget the idea of trying to get this working with Websites?